# Git: Fresh branches pull obsolete content from master

Tags: git, github, branch

Symptom: Newly created Git branches repeatedly pull an obsolete/stale image of the upstream repo. A new branch omits the most recently merged commit or commits.

I encountered this when creating branches using the GitHub Desktop GUI client, on Mac OS Sierra:

[image: New-branch widget in Git Desktop GUI client]

Comment: You should elaborate your question more than this if you want to answer it yourself.  It is not clear what the exact problem is just from your one sentence description.

Comment: There were bigger problems here! I've expanded both the Q and the A.

Answer (score 0):

Resolutions:

(1) In my case, I apparently just wasn't respecting GitHub's latency. GitHub seems to need a few minutes to acknowledge a merged commit. So if you pull a new branch immediately after merging, you likely haven't given GitHub time to reflect and serve up the new content.

(2) Restart your computer – this is a suspect suggestion. A peer suggested restarting, because my computer had been running the same session for 3+ weeks. The restart seemed effective, because the branch that I pulled afterwards included recent commits. But I think this was a red herring: It worked because restarting provided a time lag for GitHub to catch up. The next branch that I pulled, immediately after a merge, was again out-of-sync.

(3) Another peer suggested creating new branches using this specific syntax. Haven't tried this yet:

`git fetch --all; git checkout <upstream-name>/master -b <new_branch_name>`

(4) Consensus last resort from several peers is: Assume that your Git client has lost sync with its repo, for any of several reasons that are hard to diagnose. Rename or back up your local copy of the problem repo, and pull a branch to a fresh/empty local directory. (A beyond-last resort is to delete your fork, and create an entirely new fork of the upstream repo on your GitHub account.)